# Is deleting an website account a lack of integrity?

Tags: virtue-ethics, internet

Is deleting an website account a lack of integrity? It definitely shows a lack of control, and I'm not entirely sure how those are different. What if we have a jecklyll and hyde like internal life, and at times it can feel more pressing that we act *oddly* with that account?

Comment: Just deleting for whatever reason or none at all? Why would it show lack (or abundance, for that matter) of anything? There is a reason we have those rules about missing context.

Comment: yeah i tend to agree it's just... it does limit out future actions etc. @Conifold which afaict is a hallmark of a lack of integrity.

Comment: A related query: Does *closing* a *question* amount to a lack of integrity?

Comment: sorry if you didn't get the joke. there wasn't much to it @MikhailKatz

Answer (score 3):

This might not be entirely pertinent, but it seems to speak to a dimension or part of your concerns (this is from [an SEP article on search-engine ethics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-search/#LegLiaRig)):

> 4.2.1 The Right to Erasure (RtE)

> What is RtE, and why has it been controversial from the point of view of moral accountability issues for SECs? We can trace the origin of what eventually became the RtE debate to 2010, when Mario Costeja González requested that Google remove a link included in its list of returns for online searches of his name (see, for example, Google Spain SL, Google Inc. 2014). The link in question was to an article in a Spanish newspaper (La Vanguardia) about a home foreclosure that occurred 16 years earlier. González, a Spanish citizen, petitioned Spain’s National Data Protection Agency, to have the link removed. He argued that the information about his foreclosure, which was still prominently displayed in Google’s list of search returns for “Mario González,” was no longer “relevant.” Although the Spanish court ruled in González’s favor in 2010, many critics were unsure that this court’s ruling would also hold in other EU countries. So, these critics were not surprised when Google appealed the Spanish court’s ruling.

> As the debate in Europe escalated, many RtE advocates argued that the (former) EU Directive on Data Protection (Directive 95/46/EC), which protects the privacy rights citizens of all EU countries, includes language that indirectly supported RtE. For example, they noted that Article 12 (“Right of Access”) of that directive grants “the rectification, erasure, or blocking of data the processing of which does not comply with the provisions of the Directive because the information is … inaccurate” (see the European Commission’s “Fact Sheet on ‘The Right to Be Forgotten’ Ruling”). So, citizens of EU countries already had an explicit legal right to have *inaccurate* personal information about them removed/erased from the Internet, or at least de-linked or de-indexed from search engines. Some RtE supporters also believed that Article 12 could be interpreted to imply a right to the erasure/de-linking of online personal information that is no longer deemed to be *relevant*.

> SECs and other RtE opponents, including publishers and journalists, have viewed RtE from a very different perspective. They argued that RtE would censor information, thereby limiting freedom of expression, and would degrade the overall quality of the Internet by limiting the amount of online information available to users (see, for example, Tavani 2018). Because of these and related concerns, they concluded that the public would be *harmed* by RtE. However, some RtE supporters, including Bottis (2014, 2), suggested that RtE-related data protection was needed precisely because it would help to eliminate harm – viz., “psychological harm” (and possibly even physical harm in some cases) – that users might otherwise experience. Consider, for example, that victims of “revenge porn” sites would have explicit legal recourse regarding their requests to remove/de-index links that associated their names with those controversial sites (see the account of revenge porn vis-à-vis the Right to Be Forgotten, now RtE, in Kritikos 2018).

> In 2012, the European Commission (EC) proposed a revised Data-Protection Regulation (Article 17) for the (former) EU Directive, which included specific provisions for the removal (i.e., the “rectification, erasure, or blocking”) of personal data that was *irrelevant* (as well as personal data that was “inaccurate,” “inadequate,” or “excessive”). The EU Parliament approved the EC’s recommendations in 2013, after making a few minor modifications to Article 17 and renaming the “right” in question the “Right to Erasure.” Perhaps not surprisingly, the newly revised RtE regulation was challenged by Google and other corporations operating in Europe. However, in May 2014, the Court of Justice of the European Union (CJEU) upheld the Spanish court’s (2010) ruling in the González case, also confirming Article 17 of the updated EU Directive on Data Protection. The high court’s ruling confirmed that citizens residing in all EU nations have the right, under certain conditions, to request that search engine operators remove links to some kinds of personal information about them that are “no longer relevant.” The CJEU also noted, however, that RtE is not an absolute right; for example, this right would have to be balanced against other rights, including “freedom of expression” (see the EU’s “Fact Sheet on the ‘Right to Be Forgotten’ Ruling”).

> Although Google announced that it would comply with the CJEU’s ruling, it also worried that it would not be able to respond to all of the users’ requests that it would likely receive to remove/de-index links; doing so, it suggested, would not only be an onerous task but might also be a practical impossibility. Kelion (2019) notes that in the time period between the CJEU’s May 2014 ruling and September 2019, Google had received “more than 845,000 requests to remove a total of 3.3 million web addresses,” which resulted in approximately “45% of the links ultimately getting delisted.” So it would seem that Google and its supporters indeed have a reasonable concern, given the magnitude of removal requests it has received. But one can still reasonably ask, as Bottis has, whether the sheer volume of these requests constitutes sufficient grounds for repealing RtE.

> Bottis points out we do not cease to enact and to comply with laws that apply in physical space simply because their enforcement could not possibly eliminate crimes such as prostitution, drug dealing, etc. She further notes that in the digital world, protecting privacy and copyright has sometimes seemed impossible to achieve, but we still propose, enact, and enforce laws to protect both as best we can. So on this view, we could not justify “de-legislating” RtE solely on the grounds that it is difficult to enforce. But it is also worth noting that as in the case of Google’s arguments for repealing RtE, many of the arguments advanced by RtE’s supporters also include one or more logical fallacies; an analysis of some of those fallacious arguments is included in Tavani (2018).

> In one sense, the debate about RtE (formerly referred to as the RTBF debate) would now seem moot, in Europe at least, following the CJEU’s 2014 ruling and its later approval of the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR), which was adopted by the EU in April 2016 and went into effect in May 2018. Yet, a new and different kind of debate concerning RtE has since replaced the original – viz., a dispute about (i) how RtE should be implemented in the EU, especially in light of what some have criticized as the “vague” guidelines given to SECs; and (ii) whether RtE needs to be universally applied to be effective. With respect to (i), Google and other SECs claimed that the CJEU did not provide sufficiently clear and precise criteria for guiding them in determining which requests for removal/deletion merit serious consideration and which do not. So, Google and other SECs continue to examine RtE requests on a case-by-case basis.

> Regarding (ii), many privacy advocates argue that while RtE applies in all EU countries, it cannot be an effective law without strong international support; so, many members of the EC, as well as the privacy regulators in the 28 EU nations (including the UK which will soon exit the EU but will likely continue to support the principles comprising RtE), have argued that RtE should apply beyond Europe. Even though SECs operating in Europe are required to comply with GDPR (and its RtE provisions) in all EU countries, RtE can be very easily circumvented both within and outside Europe. For example, a European user who enters the keyword “Mario González” on Google.com (or on non-local (European) versions of Bing, Yahoo, DuckDuckGo, etc.) will still find the link to the story about that person’s home foreclosure prominently listed, even though users of Google.es (in Spain), or Google users in other EU countries such as Germany (Google.de), will not see that link in their list of search returns. So RtE supporters have petitioned for broader application of the new law, while Google and other SECs have challenged that view in court. In September 2019, the EU’s highest court ruled that Google did not have to apply RtE globally (Kelion 2019). So, many privacy advocates in Europe and elsewhere believe that a universal or global version of RtE is still needed for it to be an effective law (see, for example, Global Partners Digital 2018).

See also e.g. ["The Ethics of Identity and Community on Social Networking Services"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-social-networking/#EthIdeComSocNetSer) as well as the SEP article regarding [privacy and information technology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/it-privacy/).

Comment: ok. i wasn't specifically asking about whether we have a right to delete ourselves, rather than how it reflects on us and our virtue to be constantly exerting that right. specifically interested in integrity here

Comment: i cliclked on the ethics link, and wondered if you knew what 'contextual integrity' means. it looks almost the same as fidelity, so how does integrity come into play here?

Comment: Maybe we should have to explicitly post / opt in to things showing about ourselves rather than have it be the default?

Comment: well absolutely yes @ScottRowe there are few things i need to hide from the world, but that isn't necessarily the same as being shameless..